# Displaying content in uiwebview

Tags: uiwebview

I want to display information from web page in UIWebView. But the problem is website has headers, ads on the side etc. I want to display only the main content. Is this possible by any means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a website? You could create a css specially for iPhone browser

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iPhone.css">
```

This stylesheet would be called only by an iPhone device.

Comment: Thank you the answer. I am trying to develop an xcode application for a course project and I want one of my tabs in the application to display a web page. Say http://www.uhhospitals.org/rainbowchildren/HealthInformation/PediatricDrugDosageInformation/PseudoephedrineDosageTable.aspx .I want to display only the table and contents below the table.